# I have a problem with the function.php in the wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have problem with the style and js function its not displayed. here is my function.php I already add wp_head in header.php and wp_footer and the stlye is not displayed.

```html
<?php 
function gt_setup(){

wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts','//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@100&family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap');

wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome','//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css');
wp_enqueue_style('style',get_stylesheet_uri(),NUll,microtime(),all);
wp_enqueue_script("main",get_theme_file_uri('js/main.js'),true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','gt_setup');
?>
```

Comment: Is your file named `function.php` or `functions.php`?

Answer (score 0):

as Bruno pointed, rename your file to functions.php and use this code:
i had removed wrong syntax and add right syntax to call your script in footer

```
<?php
function gt_setup(){

    wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts','//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@100&family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap');

    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome','//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style',get_stylesheet_uri(),NUll,microtime());
    wp_enqueue_script("main",get_theme_file_uri('js/main.js'),[],'',true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','gt_setup');
?>
```

Comment: Problem resolved thank very much my file I forget the "s" by rename the fuctions.php.